# What's the difference between the name of a foreign key generated by Hibernate and the one I choose?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys

I'm little confused, but when we create a foreign key, we dont name it as we want, but we replace it with the name generated by Hibernate like that "FKFAEFA94EE50A59CF". Why we should keep the one generated by Hibernate ?

Comment: You shouldn't. Prefer well-named, meaningful foreign key constraints, to be able to identify a violation more easily. It's easier to know what a violation of ORDER_REFERENCES_PRODUCT_FK is than what a violation of FKFAEFA94EE50A59CF is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure there isn't much difference between the two. However when it comes down to identifying foreign key constraints being violated within the `dbms`. It is much easier to identify `FK_PURCHASE` or `FK_YOUR_CONSTRAINT_HERE` than reading a bunch of random letters generated by Hibernate.